# Booking calculator using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am trying to create a calculator to calculate the price of selected objects in this `form`. But the problem I am facing, is my lack of skill within `Javascript`.

Currently I have created a very simple setup, but it is still alot of job to be done to make it work, or at least that is what I believe.

Then comes my question, I want it to be able to calculate depending on currently `selected objects`, and amount of days one wish to stay.

As of right now, the only thing I've got going is the very last textbox, there it displays the objects selected on the checkboxes. What I want it to do is to be able to display every object selected into it together with a total price.
example: "You wish to order `[selectDestination]` for `[days]` with `[selectRom]` single rooms and `[selectRom2]` double rooms. Wish/wish not to rent equipment depending on what is clicked on in checkboxes. For total `[endPrice]`"

I know I am asking for a lot here. Any help is more than welcome. But if anything seem unclear or too broad to ask about. Please leave a comment below and I'll respond and try to make it more obvious what I am asking for.

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/sa6bLukq/1/

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectDestinasjon");
var options = [{
  "place": "Konsberg",
  "price": "$20"
}, {
  "place": "Trysil",
  "price": "$30"
}, {
  "place": "Beitostølen",
  "price": "$40"
}];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt.place;
  el.value = opt.price;
  select.appendChild(el);
}


var select = document.getElementById("selectRom");
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectRom2");
var options = ["1", "2", "3"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  var el2 = document.createElement("option");
  el2.textContent = opt;
  el2.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
  select2.appendChild(el2);
}

function myFunction() {
  var coffee = document.forms[0];
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + coffee[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("order").value = "You wish to order: " + txt;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="">
    <br><b>Where do you want to go</b>
    <br>
    <select id="selectDestinasjon">
      <option>Choose a destination</option>
    </select>
    <br><b>Pick a booking date</b>
    <br>
    <input type="date">
    <br><b>Amount of days you wish to stay</b>
    <br>
    <input type="number">
    <br><b>How many single rooms? </b>
    <br>
    <select id="selectRom">
      <option>How many single rooms?</option>
    </select>
    <br><b>How many double rooms?</b>
    <br>
    <select id="selectRom2">
      <option>How many double rooms?</option>
    </select>
    <br>Skipass 200kr:
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="Skipass">
    <br>Ski Equipment 1000kr:
    <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="Ski Equipment">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Confirm order">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="order" size="50">

</div>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: For one thing yu will want to give IDs to all your select elements, not just some of them.

Comment: As said, I know there is alot of work to be done, and not all of them have been defined as I am not totaly sure how to define everything.

Comment: I'll try to help you, i need to know if u can use Jquery or if you need a full javascript solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see why this question is likely off topic - HINT: SO is not elance.com :)

Comment: Jquery is fine, and thanks! :)

Comment: The price is calculated only with the destination? not with time/location or not/number of room ?

Comment: The price is calculated based on rooms, destination, duration and possible equipment. did I forget to write that :3?

Comment: Idk, you specified a price only for destination in the option

Comment: Oh my bad then, I want it to calculate the total price of everything, you got any clue how to :3?

Comment: If not price, you know how to make it display all the selected objects in the box at the very end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try something, with what i understood. My english is limited, so maybe i miss-understood something. But there is my solution :

First add "id" and "data-price" attribute to each element, for select them easily, then set a data-price for calcul tour total-price.
I also change your "order" field to textarea for better display.

```
    <div>
        <form action="">
            <br><b>Where do you want to go</b>
            <br><select id="selectDestinasjon">
                  <option>Choose a destination</option>
                </select>
            <br><b>Pick a booking date</b>
            <br><input type="date" id="date">

            <br><b>Amount of days you wish to stay</b>
            <br><input type="number" id="number" data-price="20">

            <br><b>How many single rooms? </b>
            <br><select id="selectRom" data-price="12">
                  <option>How many single rooms?</option>
                </select>

            <br><b>How many double rooms?</b>
            <br><select id="selectRom2" data-price="15">
                  <option>How many double rooms?</option>
                </select>

            <br>Skipass 200kr:<input type="checkbox" id="skipass" value="Skipass" data-price="45">

            <br>Ski Equipment 1000kr:<input type="checkbox" id="equipment" value="Ski Equipment" data-price="100">

            <br>
            <input type="button" id="myb" value="Confirm order">
            <br>
            <textarea id="order" cols="35" rows="7"></textarea>

        </form>
        <div id="totalPrice"></div>
    </div>
```

Then the Javascrip/Jquery :
 I kept your select initialiation, I just remove the "$" to price on you option.
And i rewrite "myFunction" for calculationg total, and write on a single string, every selected item :

```
  $("#myb").click(function() {
        var price = 0;
      var txt = "";
        txt += "You wish to order "+$("#selectDestinasjon option:selected").text();
      price = $("#selectDestinasjon").val();

      txt += " the "+$("#date").val();

      txt += " for "+$("#number").val()+" days";
      price *= $("#number").val();

      txt += " with "+$("#selectRom option:selected").text()+ " single rooms";
      price += $("#selectRom").data("price")*parseFloat($("#selectRom option:selected").text());

      txt += " and "+$("#selectRom2 option:selected").text()+ " double rooms.";
      price += $("#selectRom2").data("price")*parseFloat($("#selectRom2 option:selected").text());

      if ($("#skipass").prop("checked") && $("#equipment").prop("checked") ) {
            txt += " Wish a skipass and equipment to rent.";
          price += $("#skipass").data("price")+$("#equipment").data("price");
      } else if ($("#skipass").prop("checked") ) {
          txt += " Wish a skipass.";
          price += $("#skipass").data("price");
      } else if ($("#equipment").prop("checked") ) {
            txt += " Wish to rent equipment.";
          price +=  $("#equipment").data("price");
      } else {
         txt += " Wish not to rent equipement.";
      }
      $("#order").val(txt);
      $("#totalPrice").text(price+"$");

  })
```

You can try this solution on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa6bLukq/3/)

Comment: Hands down to you sir, exact solution I were looking for. Give this man a medal. The real MVP. Thank you so much!.

Comment: Did you include jquery ?